# Exposing the localhost to the world always gives 5** [ngrok, localtunnel, etc]

Tags: localhost, webserver, ngrok, tunnel, localtunnel

I have a React JS app that started with a local server using the command: `react-scripts start`:

```sh
Compiled successfully!

You can now view telco-widget in the browser.

  Local:            http://localhost:3000/
  On Your Network:  http://192.168.0.117:3000/

Note that the development build is not optimized.
To create a production build, use yarn build.
```

I want to expose the localhost to the world, so I've tried [ngrok](https://ngrok.com/):

```sh
ngrok http 3000
```

which gives the valid output:

```sh
Session Status                online                                                                                                        
Account                       xxx (Plan: Free)                                                                                              
Version                       2.3.35                                                                                                        
Region                        Europe (eu)                                                                                                   
Web Interface                 http://127.0.0.1:4040                                                                                         
Forwarding                    http://xxx.eu.ngrok.io -> http://localhost:3000                                                      
Forwarding                    https://xxx.eu.ngrok.io -> http://localhost:3000                                                     
                                                                                                                                            
Connections                   ttl     opn     rt1     rt5     p50     p90                                                                   
                              0       0       0.00    0.00    0.00    0.00
```

but once I try to reach the `https://xxx.eu.ngrok.io` I see an error:

[image]

I also tried:

- `ngrok` alternatives like [`localtunnel`](https://github.com/localtunnel/localtunnel) but the result is similar: 504 error
- changing the port for the webserver
- serving local directories with `ngrok` (working well: `ngrok http file:///Users/me/share`) instead of localhost
- using clean `etc/hosts`

Versions of the tools:

- react-scripts - 3.1.2
- yarn - 1.22.4
- ngrok - 2.3.35
- localtunnel - 2.0.0

Answer (score 0):

Dude! your web server is not running.

Make sure your server is running and try to open link localhost:3000 in browser.
then let me know if still you've any issue.

Comment: Thank you for your reply. The server is running. I can open `localhost:3000` and I see rendered fully functional react app. The result is the same for the local network IP.